# Is it possible to create a custom index on Postgres catalog table pg_largeobject?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, blob

I am aware of the fact that large objects are stored in a separate table called `pg_largeobject`, which stores `b-tree` indexed rows, and the user table merely stores the Oid of the object stored in `pg_largeobject`.

Now, creating an index on the column which stores just the Oid(s) is kind of absurd. So, can we create custom indexes on the `pg_largeobject` table for better performance of data retrieval and stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do that, because `pg_largeobject` is a system catalog. It also wouldn't do you much good, since the objects are stored in chunks there.

If you want to index a large object, you are doing something wrong. The large object would be too large for fitting into an index entry anyway, and who wants to search like `WHERE blob = '...'`?

I suspect that you have some information stored *inside* the large object that you would like to index, like the (benighted) idea of keeping your state in a JSON, storing that as large object and then index one of its attributes.

It would be better to store such attributes that you want to search for *outside* the large object as regular table columns, then the problem would go away.

That said, in PostgreSQL you can define indexes on expressions, so if you use `bytea` rather than a large object (which is preferable for smaller binary data anyway), you can define an index on an expression that extracts the desired attribute from the binary data. You cannot do that with a large object, because the functions to access large objects are not `IMMUTABLE`, as the contents of a large object can change, while the `oid` stays the same.